# Enable Bluetooth Keyboard before LUKS decryption - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, encryption, luks

I need to have my Keychron K8 Bluetooth keyboard working to write
my boot-time LUKS disk decryption password.

At the moment, I can only use the laptop keyboard as the Bluetooth stack
is not enabled yet.

I found (but not tried yet) the way to enable the module at *initramfs* time but
I'm not sure how it is related to the Systemd Bluetooth Service.

Has anyone with the same issue got a solution?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

1. Update initramfs: Update your initramfs image to include the necessary Bluetooth components. You can do this with the following command:

   `sudo update-initramfs -u`
2. Edit your kernel command line: Edit your kernel command line to include the following options:

   `rd.luks.options=luks,keyscript=/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/btdecryption`
3. Create the btdecryption script: Create a new file called "btdecryption" in the "/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top" directory, and add the following contents:

- 

```
# Wait for Bluetooth keyboard to connect
echo "Waiting for keyboard to connect..."
until hcitool con | grep -q "Keyboard Address"; do
    sleep 1
done
echo "Keyboard connected."

# Get password from keyboard
echo "Enter password:"
password=""
while [ ${#password} -lt 1 ]; do
    read -s -n 1 char
    if [ "$char" == "" ]; then
        echo ""
        break
    fi
    password="$password$char"
    echo -n "*"
done

# Pass password to LUKS
echo $password
```

4. Make the script executable: Make the "btdecryption" script executable with the following command:

   `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/btdecryption`
5. Update initramfs again: Update your initramfs image again to include the new script:

   `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: How can I edit my kernel command line? Where should the line be added?

Comment: Step 1 is unnecessary, given step 5 runs it again.  The while loop in the script seems to be "read one character while the length of the password is less than 1 character" so it looks as if it would terminate after the first letter?  Why not `while :; do` to loop until the user presses Enter and the `break` gets executed?

Comment: @jotrocken the kernel command line can be edited by changing /etc/default/grub (see the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX options) and then running `sudo update-grub`.  I suspect that this will not help you, since `keyscript=/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/btdecryption` does not look right -- in the initramfs the script is copied to a different location, and the full /usr/ is not mounted yet.